# Google Translate tool will not make translation preference persist across multiple pages

Tags: jquery, internationalization, translation, google-translate

Google Translate Tools let you embed a translation dropdown in your website that lets users translate pages. However, this preference is only for that page...as soon as they click to a different page on the site, they have to re-select the language.

Any ideas on how to make this preference persistent? Is there an option for Google Translate that I'm missing (it seems like this would be an extremely common use case)? Or am I stuck using jQuery to set a cookie and then trigger a click event for the desired <option> on each page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using http://translateth.is instead. It has this feature included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this,

An example: http://sitehelp.com.au/jtranslate/

Answer (score 0):

From [google translate support](http://translate.google.com/support/?hl=en):

> Translate an entire web page directly from Google Translate, simply by entering its address (e.g. "www.google.com") into the input box and clicking **Translate**.

It means going on http://translate.google.com/ and doing that. I believe it even gives a different translation from the *Tools*.